# Redirect Permanent with regex in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect 301 this :

```
www.url.eu/en/my-slug-here to www.url.com/en/my-slug-here
```

`RedirectPermanent /en/my-slug-here www.url.com/en/my-slug-here` is not enough, because I want to redirect all the URL who is prefixed by www.url.eu/

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.url\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.url.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)url\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.url.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.url.com [R=301,L] don't keep the slug part is'n it?  I need to keep this part /en/my-slug-here after the www.url.com

Comment: for the remaining part we can add the `/$1` in redirected domain